# SPFx breakpoints and debugging from Visual Studio Code instead from Chrome

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I am trying to find a way to debug my local SPFx workbench from Visual Studio Code instead from Chrome, but I could not find any guides on how to attach the Chrome to Visual Studio Code and hit a breakpoint in my react typescript webpart (web app). Are there any good guides on how to do it?

This may be something trivial, but I am new to the react-gulp-vs code world and in the past, it was relatively easy to debug javascript with Visual Studio and IExplorer and I am wondering if easy setup exists with Visual Studio Code as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a project on codeplex that's supposed to let you do this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug
I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Hey, it seems its supported natively in vs code now! See this https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code

Comment: Not natively, the article https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code you point actually states you need to install first the same VSCode extension as explained in your first link https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug.